# How to extract the uid value from id on Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

In linux if you type `id www-data` you get the id.

```
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Is there a way to extract the value for the uid from this?

I think I could pipe it like this:

```
id www-data | grep ?
```

I could also use `egrep` or `sed` if its easier, but not sure how to proceed.
Similar examples on Stackoverflow deal with the direct extraction of the value via regex. I don't know if the value would be 33. Hence I need to extract it from `uid=` until `(www-data)`. (unless that is always 33, and I am making my life too difficult). Any suggestion?

Comment: How about `id -u www-data`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, you can use the flags of `id` (from `man id`):

```
-g, --group
       print only the effective group ID
-G, --groups
       print all group IDs
-n, --name
       print a name instead of a number, for -ugG
-r, --real
       print the real ID instead of the effective ID, with -ugG
-u, --user
       print only the effective user ID
```

This is probably less error prone: if in the future `id` would change the way it formats the output, the flag will still work.

So use:

```
$ id -u www-data
33
```

In general many of these commands offer flags to retrieve parts of the information. Consulting the *manpage* in general results in a lot of options and only occasionally you find you need something that is not implemented.

Comment: I changed the question to reflect the answer better,

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep,

```
id www-data | grep -oP 'uid=\K\S+'
```

OR

sed,

```
id www-data | sed -n 's/.*\buid=\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p'
```